Implementation of STL Emplace( ) Method for a Template Queue ADT in Cpp
I got a my implementation of STL queue data structure in C++ with a template class. I'm facing a problem that is implementation of emplace ( ) method for this template ADT. In emplace we use receiving arguments to construct object of a specific data type with constructor.I have no way to implement the logic of constructing that object with these receiving arguments in a general way for all data types. Can anyone help to implement its logic?
I think there is only one way for it that is doing hard code , ie. not a general implementation for all data types.

Use T(args...)?

Sir it will allow us to take a variable amount of parameters. But problem is that how to use these variable number of arguments to construct an object?

You can call the constructor directly and construct an object in a particular location (say, p):
::new (p) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
If you are compiling with C++20 or later, you can use std::construct_at which does basically that.

Kindly can u further explain it with th ehelp of some example code.

template
class Queue
{
T* queue;
int sizeOfQueue;
int frnt;
int rear;
void reSize(int newSize);
public:
Queue(const int cnt =0, ...);
Queue(const Queue& ref);
Queue(Queue&& ref);
T& front();
T& back();
void emplace(int countOfParameters, ... );
void push(const T& ele);
void pop();
int size()const;
bool empty() const;
void swap(Queue& other);
void displayQueue()const;
~Queue();
};
It's prototype of my class, now can u help me guess how to implement emplace ( ) for Queue where T may be a built in data type or a user defined data type.

Edit your question with above code.
